# What am I Doing Wrong in my direct SQL Query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My view model:

```
public class LocationsWithHierarchyViewModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Lineage { get; set; }
}
```

My query (tested in SQL, works):

```
        string cmd = string.Format(@"
            SELECT Locations.Id, Locations.Name, LocationHierarchy.Lineage
            FROM Locations
            LEFT JOIN LocationHierarchy
            ON Locations.Id = LocationHierarchy.Id
            WHERE OfficeId = {0}; 
            ", 1);
```

The part of the code that I am sure is causing the problem:

```
var locationsInOffice = db.Database.SqlQuery(cmd).ToList<LocationsWithHierarchyViewModel>();
```

The error is that I must specify the return type for the data, which is List. How do?

P.S. - "db" is our db context, I can't use it with a normal EF query because we don't have a model for the LocationHierarchy table, long story.

> The type argument for method
>   'System.Data.Entity.Database.SqlQuery(string,
>   parmsobject[]_' cannot be inferred from usage. Try specifying the type
>   arguments explicitly.

Comment: Why not to post exact error?

Comment: `db.Database.SqlQuery<LocationsWithHierarchyViewModel>(cmd)`

Comment: @lad2025: post this as an answer.

Comment: @lad2025: That did it: db.Database.SqlQuery<LocationsWithHierarchyViewModel>(cmd).ToList(), thanks. And yea - if you post it as the answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As error message says: Specify type arguments explicitly.

```
db.Database.SqlQuery<LocationsWithHierarchyViewModel>(cmd).ToList()
```